# What is the difference between a[x] && a.x

Tags: javascript

I wonder  what difference between `a[x]` and `a.x`

When I create `a={}`

when I write `a.x=5` it gives `{x:5}`

but when I write `a[x]=5` it gives error

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: `a[x]` and `a.x` are very different, but `a['x']` and `a.x` are very similar.

Comment: "a[x]=5 it gives error" because it is looking for a variable `x` which you did not define. If you defined a variable x, it would be the string `var x = 'x'; console.log(a[x]);`

Comment: In case of `a[x]`, javascript will look for an identifier named `x` and if it exists then its value will be used as a property name. If it doesn't exists, you will get an error

Comment: `x = 'y'; return a[x];` would give you the same result as `return a.y`